# Android keeping connection alive to receive constant data update from server

Tags: android, httprequest

i hope you can help me with my problem. I have to instantiate an http connection and do a get call to the server. 
After this call i have to check periodically if the server sent me some data (the connection must not be closed after the first data received). If it does, then i have to parse this data and pass it to an activity and wait again.

My problem is to understand if i'm doing correctly this thing. Here my code

```
try {
        URL url = getUrl();
        URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
        HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
        httpConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        httpConnection.connect();

        while(true) {
            sleep(5000);
            int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();

            if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                InputStream inputStream = httpConnection.getInputStream();
                String response = null;

                if(inputStream.available() > 0) {
                    long length = inputStream.available();
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) length];
                    inputStream.read(bytes);
                    response = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
                }
            }
        }                   
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

`getUrl()` function gives me the complete url that i have to call.
Then i connect through `httpConnection.connect();`.

while i'm iterating is the connection already opend and capable of receiving incoming data?

I apologize for my english. Thanks a lot

Francesco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the official android documentation

> Uses of this class follow a pattern:
>
> 1. Obtain a new HttpURLConnection by calling URL.openConnection() and
>    casting the result to HttpURLConnection.
> 2. Prepare the request. The
>    primary property of a request is its URI. Request headers may also
>    include metadata such as credentials, preferred content types, and
>    session cookies.
> 3. Optionally upload a request body. Instances must be
>    configured with setDoOutput(true) if they include a request body.
>    Transmit data by writing to the stream returned by getOutputStream().
> 4. Read the response. Response headers typically include metadata such as
>    the response body's content type and length, modified dates and
>    session cookies. The response body may be read from the stream
>    returned by getInputStream(). If the response has no body, that method
>    returns an empty stream.
> 5. Disconnect. Once the response body has been
>    read, the HttpURLConnection should be closed by calling disconnect().
>    Disconnecting releases the resources held by a connection so they may
>    be closed or reused.

As you see from this quote, if you need to send some data to a host you just need to call `setDoOutput(true)` and use `OutputStream` of your connection to send data to the host. In this case you use "POST" request method after you called `setDoOutput(true)`. If you don't need to send data, but just to connect to the host and retrieve data, you also don't need to call `setRequestMethod("GET")`, because it's default request method.

When you connect to the host, just use `InputStream` to get data from it.